# using wget wrapped in python2.7 subprocess runs for ever

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, wget

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmdlist = ['wget', '--no-host-directories', '--mirror', '--no-parent', '--reject', '\'index.html*\'', 'http://abc.blah.com/dir/']

p = Popen(cmdlist, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.name = 'foo'

while p.poll() is None:
    print "#",
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

(stdout,stderr) = p.communicate()
returncode = p.returncode

if returncode == 0:
    print "Happy"
else:
    print "Sad rc = {0}".format(returncode),
    print "stdout = \"{0}\"".format(stdout.strip()),
    print "stderr = \"{0}\"".format(stderr.strip())
```

This runs for ever on a very small directory. I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 1):

The `wget` process will eventually block because it is waiting for its `stdout` or `stderr` pipe to become writable if it writes enough to fill the kernel's buffer for that pipe. This is just how pipes work in Unix, by default: the writer process will get slowed down to match the speed of the reader process, and if the reader stops reading, the writer stops writing (and if the reader exits, the writer is killed!)

There are a few different ways to fix this.

- To prevent the buffer from becoming full, read from both `p.stdout` and `p.stderr`. Be careful not to block on `stdout` while `wget` is blocked on `stderr`, and vice versa... you have to read from both simultaneously.  This is how `p.communicate()` works internally. This is the most complicated solution, but if you look at the source code for `Popen._communicate` in `subprocess.py` you'll see how it's supposed to work.
- Remove the `while p.poll() is None` loop from your code.
- Don't redirect `wget` to a pipe, redirect it to something else like a regular file or `/dev/null`.

Comment: I think another issue with the OP's code is that `'--reject', '\'index.html*\''` may not actually work.

Comment: @Blender: That would be a great comment to put on the question, but if you put the comment here, the OP might miss it :-)

Comment: @Blender You are right, it did not work. Do you know why ? And how can I make it work ?

Comment: @abc: I'd try removing the escaped quotes.